# Bluetooth Connection?

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I am facing some issues connecting with 32feet.net library in my C# window mobile application?

Can you please guide me how to connect with blue tooth with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to accomplish and what issues do you have?

I have a short blog post describing how to enumerate Bluetooth devices using .NETCF and 32feet.NET

http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2010/07/enumerating-bluetooth-devices-from.html

Comment: Thanks for your help..:) i got my issue resolved with Microsoft Share Resource Tools for Bluetooth..